# How to recycle a TCP port after server being killed?

Tags: python, windows, sockets

I use python to write a simple RPC server, which listens on port 80.

The OS is windows 7.

In case some errors occur, the server got stuck and it will be killed and then restarted. But when it is restarted, the port 80 is not released yet and it cannot bind to 80 and thus cannot work.

If I wait some more time and then try to restart it again, it will succeed.

I'm wondering how can I force to recycle the port when the server process got killed?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did the server set the `SO_REUSEADDR` socket option prior to binding to port 80 in the first place? If it did, then you shouldn't be experiencing this delay. If it did not, then I'm afraid you just have to wait for the delay to expire. In the latter case, while you patiently wait for the delay to expire, you can add `setsockopt(socket_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &one)` to your code so that this doesn't happen the *next* time.

Comment: I didn't set SO_REUSEADDR. I'll try as you suggested. Thanks.